# Having trouble setting up data calling with rmnet_data0 interface

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, ping

I'm trying to set up a data call through `rmnet_dataX` interface which is referring to a cellular connection through the card inserted, but having trouble doing so. I do the following

```
ifconfig rmnet_data0 up
```

I then assign an IP statically

```
rmnet_data0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.246.68.132  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Add the default path in the routing table

```
ip ro add default via 10.246.68.132 dev rmnet_data0
```

Add the DNS server

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Set NAT rules

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o rmnet_data0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Routing table

```
netstat -r 

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface

default         10.246.68.132   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 rmnet_data0
10.0.0.0        *               255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 rmnet_data0
192.168.225.0   *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 bridge0
```

```
ping google.com // fails
```

Also, the default path really just indicates the packets coming to the gateway IP are routed to the external network which in this case is network data?

Given that, are NAT rules really required?

Comment: The NAT rules are only required if you have some other machines behind the computer you are doing this on (which according to your routing table, you probably don't). The more interesting question is how you know the static IP and gateway given you connect to a cellular network, and if the nameserver you are using is blocked or not. Usually the cellular network would give you that information, e.g. via DHCP.

Comment: Mind elaborating on your first point? Wouldn't routing be only necessary when you are trying to access/route packets to an external network? And spot on about static IP assignment - it was random. Using a static IP won't be recognized by the cellular network thus no connectiviy? Also, I see DHCP app running in the output of `ps aux` but how/when would it assign the IP to `rmnet_data0` though?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some network basics (please read up on details, there's plenty of resources online):

- The routing tables are both for packets originating on this machine, and for packets incoming from other machines that are forwarded (forwarding needs to be enabled for that). So routing tables are **always** necessary for any networking.
- Network address translation (NAT) is only necessary when (1) packets coming from other computers are forwarded to your cellular network, and (2) your cellular network only recognizes a single client (which is normally the case), and you need to pretend that packets coming from other computers are coming from this computer, and not from the other computers.
- The steps to get it working are first to get it working on this computer. If you do need forwarding and NAT, that's the second step. So initially, no firewall rules.
- You need to run a specific DHCP client that handles this particular interface. Details depend on your system; the configuration for systemd, network manager, or legacy style configuration etc. are all different. Figure out what runs on your system, google "set up DHCP with systemd" or similar.
- For DHCP, typically the DHCP client is triggered when the interface comes up, and then DHCP client broadcasts a message on the interface "hello, I'm new here, please give me an IP address an additional information". The DHCP server answers that broadcast, and tells you the IP, the gatway, and potentially more. The DHCP client program then uses this information to set up the IP address, the routing tables etc. Some cellular networks use this way, some use different ways. I have no idea what your cellular provider does.

Comment: I reckon the DHCP server is set up by the ISP which needs to run to provide an IP addres to `rmnet_data0` interface. Thing is I'm not running pure linux and some features are missing so commands like systemd aren't supported - and `etc/network/interfaces` doesn't exist either.

Comment: Yes, the DHCP server is set up by the ISP. If you have some kind of embedded system, they all usually come with some sort of small DHCP client, and means to configure it. Systemd is not necessary. Only you know what kind of system you use...

Comment: DHCP client is provided by the vendor or the network provider?